# Studies proving that vacations need to be uninterrupted?

Tags: work-life-balance, vacation, time-off, burnout

There was an article saying something like "*if a vacation is interrupted, it no longer counts*", and it backed that claim with studies. As I tend to agree with it more and more, I want to find that article (or those studies), but I can't. I remember it being a reputable source.

In my interpretation, the logic was this:

> While the importance of cutting off during your personal time may be obvious, the studies have proved *not* doing that may negatively impact the result of your vacation. Merely answering an e-mail (or being forced to think about work in any way) during your personal time may nullify the accumulated rest and reset the vacation-stopwatch back to zero, so that you have to start over.

It was probably phrased in a less dramatic way, but the main point remains.

I read through [vacation](/questions/tagged/vacation) and googled all kinds of keywords, but the closest I got was [«Vacation, interrupted» on BBC Capital](http://www.bbc.com/capital/story/20140718-holiday-interrupted), which is close, but not what I'm looking for.

Could it have been my wishful thinking?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be about navigating the Workplace. Can you add _why_ you want to find this article? If you have some kind of work-related goal, we might be able to help you with that (and maybe provide literature as part of the answer)

Comment: @Erik I wanted to keep the question short and removed all unnecessary details. Please be sure that I indeed have a work-related goal. If all questions should be literally about Workplace, there wouldn't have been any [tag:vacation] questions here.

Comment: @Erik the goal is avoiding burnout (don't want to appear impolite so thought I'd clarify)

Comment: The vacation questions here are all related to interacting with the Workplace during a vacation, or about requesting vacations. I think your question can be on-topic if you ask about "how to convince boss I need peace and quiet on vacation", but requesting a study probably isn't. It's not very likely to work, either. People usually aren't convinced by studies anyway. (sad as that fact may be)

Comment: @Erik there already is [a similar question about convincing a boss](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/118003/my-boss-wants-me-to-be-available-during-my-vacation-abroad). In fact, I decided to ask this because I wanted to answer that one and realised I don't have anything to back my claims. The studies won't convince my boss, but I can, and I need to ensure I'm not making this up, i.e. it's a scientifically proven fact

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not sure if it's what you're looking for, but I found this article along the same lines:
https://www.fastcompany.com/40425251/what-happens-to-your-brain-when-you-work-on-vacation

The study referenced seems to be more along the lines of memorability though.

Comment: Bear in mind that this is the internet, and you can generally find something on the internet to conform to any point of view, you're likely to be able to find studies for the opposite of this one if you searched enough.  And ordinary people often don't conform to the ideals that studies seem to propose that they do.